# Does IBM-Graph use a search index? If so, what one?

Tags: ibm-graph

My understanding is that IBM-Graph uses Titan, backed by Cassandra as it's persistent datastore.

In this stack it is usual to have a separate, search-index of Solr, Lucene or Elasticsearch, in order to enable more advanced queries like full-text search and geo-related queries.

Does IBM-Graph implement a search index such as this?  If so, which one.  And also, are these more advanced queries exposed via 'gremlin', i.e can we make use of this search index manually in order to perform full-text queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM Graph support search index by setting `composite` with false when you create an index, a Mixed index will be created by this way. FYI, the API doc: https://ibm-graph-docs.ng.bluemix.net/api.html#index-apis

But IBM Graph only support first level index, for example:

1. An index related to field `name` is available for Gremlin query `g.V().has("name","Jack")`
2. But not for the 2nd criteria `has("age",20)` in the Gremlin query `g.V().has("name","Jack").out().has("age",20)`