# Indexing in Titan/Janus

Tags: gremlin, titan, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

I have 2 questions:

1. How to index this query?

   ```
   g.V(vertexId).repeat(out().hasLabel('location')).emit().tree().next()
   ```
2. in the Titan 1.0 documentation, there are only ways given to index the graph once when the data is already inserted  .
   However in the `generate-modern.groovy` file [here](https://github.com/pluradj/titan-tp3-driver-example/blob/master/scripts/generate-modern.groovy) 
   we see that indexing is done before the creation of vertices which seems reasonable. However I am unable to do it when trying to use `buildMixedIndex` as it is throwing me

   > illegal argument exception :Unknown external index backend search

My approach was

```
def location = mgmt.makeVertexLabel("location").make()
def displayName = mgmt.makePropertyKey("displayName").dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make()
def shortName = mgmt.makePropertyKey("shortName").dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make()
def description = mgmt.makePropertyKey("description").dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make()
def latitude = mgmt.makePropertyKey("latitude").dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make()
def longitude = mgmt.makePropertyKey("longitude").dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make()

def locationByName = mgmt.buildIndex("displayNameAndShortNameAndDescriptionAndLatitudeAndLongitude", Vertex.class).addKey(displayName).addKey(shortName).addKey(description)
.addKey(latitude).addKey(longitude).indexOnly(location).buildMixedIndex('search')
```

Where I am getting it wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If that query is taking a long time, the problem is likely that it is visiting too many elements or it is stuck in an infinite loop. The existing JanusGraph/Titan indexes won't help for that. You already have a direct vertex lookup by id, `g.V(vertexId)`, and the rest of the query is traversing the neighborhood from that vertex. I'd suggest using edge labels, i.e. `out('friends')`, to limit the number of edges you visit. You could also use [`simplePath()`](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#simplepath-step) to eliminate cyclic paths. You could also use `times()` or `until()` to keep a limit on the number of times you loop with the [`repeat()`](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#repeat-step) step.
2. The configuration example you referenced only used composite indexes, which do not require an indexing backend.

[Mixed indexes](http://docs.janusgraph.org/latest/indexes.html#index-mixed) require configuring an indexing backend, either Elasticsearch, Lucene, or Solr. Pick one of these, then make sure you pass the correct configuration properties when you initialize your graph. You can find several examples in the distribution zip file in the `conf` directory. For example, in the `janusgraph-cassandra-es.properties`, you'll find:

```
index.search.backend=elasticsearch
index.search.hostname=127.0.0.1
index.search.elasticsearch.client-only=true
```

where `search` in `index.X.backend` is the chosen index configuration name you must pass to `buildMixedIndex(X)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39670730/6815248).
Both composite and mixed index are only avaiable for the first level gremlin query, not for the second level. Vertex-Centric index is required for the second level query.